# Need to prove that the zeta-function has continuos derivatives of all orders. For $x \in (1,\infty)$.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

I know the form of the derivatives of $f_n$ where $f_n$ denotes the partial sums.
And I need to show that the derivative of these partial sums uniformly converge.

---

So how would I show that the series $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^N(ln(k)/(k^x))^N$ converges uniformly.

Comment: Where does the $x$ live? Are you supposed to use the complex extension for the question of the title?

Comment: You meant $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-\ln k)^N/k^x$ and it converges uniformly for $x \ge r$ for $r > 1$. From the uniform convergence it is easy to integrate the $N$-th derivative to the get the $N-1$-th derivative which proves the claim (alternatively the limit definition of the derivative works too)